# Looking for advice: DOMDocument identifiying parent child relationships between nodes

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have an XML file that contains 2 parents nodes, and within the second parent node, there is another parent and child node.

```
<product>
<upc>677446126665</upc>
<modelNumber>Content</modelNumber>
<categoryPath>
  <category>
    <name>Content</name>
  </category>
  <category>
    <name>Content</name>
  </category>
  <category>
    <name>Content</name>
  </category>
  <category>
    <name>Content</name>
  </category>
</categoryPath>
  </product>
```

I'm not looking for someone to to give me the code, I just want to understand how this works.

Is

```
 <categoryPath> </categoryPath>
```

a child node, or a parent node? Is their a trivial approach using PHP native DOMDocument library that can allow me to remove  categoryPath completely along with each of the name node's parent node (category)

Ultimately I would have a document like this:

```
<product>
 <upc>44444</upc>
  <modelNumber>d</modelNumber>
  <name></name>
   <name></name>
    <name></name>
     <name></name>
 </product>
```

Again, I am asking about the parent child relationship between these nodes, I'm not asking for someone to just give me the code to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Parent Relationship

- `product` is the **parent** of `upc`, `modelNumber`, and  `categoryPath`.
- `categoryPath` is the **parent** of `category`.
- `category` is the **parent** of `name`.

### Child Relationship

- `name` is the **child** of `category`.
- `category` is a **child** of `categoryPath`.
- `categoryPath` is a **child** of `product`.

So `<categoryPath>` is both a parent node and a child node.

You could:

1. save each of the name nodes into a list (see
   [DOMNode::cloneNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.clonenode.php))
2. remove categoryPath (see
   [DOMNode::removeChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php))
3. add each of the name nodes back into the DOM (see
   [DOMNode::appendChild](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php))

The following XML tutorial illustrates the relationships between XML elements.

- [XML Tree - Parent](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlparent.php)
- [XML Tree - Child](http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xmlchild.php)

Comment: Excellent answer. I believe I will give each <name> tag a unique node